# generalised locally finite homology?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm reading the article "coarse homology theory" of Paul D. Mitchener.When defining the coarse homology,he used the so called "generalised locally finite homology on the category of simplicial sets",I want to know how the homology is defined.

Because I didn't learn to much about homological algebra,it would be nice to describe this homology by using the chain complex if this can be done.Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: The terminology "generalized" is too general (the pun is intended) to pin down the actual theory. Without seeing the paper, it is impossible to tell what is meant. But, most likely, he defined something which you should simply take as a definition of such theory. If you want to get an idea what one means by a "generalized homology theory", you can try to read [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/generalized+homology). But it is unclear if you have sufficient background.